# Best method of Over-clocking gtx750ti

Tags: graphics-card, overclocking

I am using Precision X by evga and using the gtx750ti I would like to know how high I can push my graphics card without damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only speed "guaranteed" to not damage your card is the factory speed. If going faster would never damage the card or cause problems, they would have sold it that way (usually). Overclocking is at your own risk.

The process of overclocking is generally to increase the overclock slowly, making sure it is stable at those settings before continuing. Once it becomes unstable, you back off to the previous settings, which you know should be stable from testing. Each card and setup is unique, so you can't know the limit until you test it out.

For reference on what others have had success with, see reviews like [this one](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2014/02/18/nvidia-geforce-gtx-750-ti-review/11), or comments on forums and store sites.